# Multi-level QTreeView

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyside, qtreeview

I'm having a hard time understanding how to set a multilevel QTree using the QTreeView and QStandardItemModel.

Here's what I have:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        tree = {'root': {
                    "1": ["A", "B", "C"],
                    "2": {
                        "2-1": ["G", "H", "I"],
                        "2-2": ["J", "K", "L"]},
                    "3": ["D", "E", "F"]}
        }

        self.tree = QTreeView(self)
        root_model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.tree.setModel(root_model)

        for r,root in enumerate(sorted(tree)):
            root_item = QStandardItem(root)
            root_model.setItem(r,root_item)

            for c,child in enumerate(sorted(tree[root])):
                child_model = QStandardItemModel(root_model)
                child_item = QStandardItem(child)
                child_model.setItem(c, child_item)

                for gc, grand_child in enumerate(sorted(tree[root][child])):
                    grand_child_model = QStandardItemModel(child_model)
                    grand_child_item = QStandardItem(grand_child)
                    grand_child_model.setItem(gc,grand_child_item)

                    if type(tree[root][child]) == dict:
                        for ggc, gran_grand_child in enumerate(sorted(tree[root][child][grand_child])):
                            gran_grand_child_model = QStandardItemModel(grand_child_model)
                            gran_grand_child_item = QStandardItem(gran_grand_child)
                            gran_grand_child_model.setItem(ggc, gran_grand_child_item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want it to look like this:

[image: tree]

So far only the 'root' item is showing, it's not throwing any error.

Also, I made this for-loops in a bit of hurry, it's kind hard to read/understand because it has too many nested for loops. I wonder if there's a better way to expand the tree based on the initial dict.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're creating a model for each item. That's wrong. You should use `.appendRow/.insertRow` on an item to add child items.

As for your loops, I'd probably use a recursive method to populate the tree. Here is what I'd do:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys
import types

class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        tree = {'root': {
                    "1": ["A", "B", "C"],
                    "2": {
                        "2-1": ["G", "H", "I"],
                        "2-2": ["J", "K", "L"]},
                    "3": ["D", "E", "F"]}
        }

        self.tree = QTreeView(self)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)

        root_model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.tree.setModel(root_model)
        self._populateTree(tree, root_model.invisibleRootItem())

    def _populateTree(self, children, parent):
        for child in sorted(children):
            child_item = QStandardItem(child)
            parent.appendRow(child_item)
            if isinstance(children, types.DictType):
                self._populateTree(children[child], child_item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**PS**: You're also not using any layouts for the main window. I added it above.

**PSv2**: Type-checking is best avoided in python, if possible, but it's kind of necessary the way you structured your `tree`. It'd be better if you structured it differently, like `dict`s all the way maybe:

```
tree = {'root': {
            '1': {'A':{}, 'B':{}, 'C':{}},
             ...
       }
```

Comment: Great, nice touch on the recursion, never would thought of that.

Comment: Your recursive loop as an inadequate stop rule, as "children" is always being iterated (will create a child for each char in a string for example)

Comment: @DanielBraun only if you do `{'foo': 'bar'}` instead of `{'foo': ['bar']}`. Anyway, this was meant as a pseudocode, more than an actual implementation. I can't write tree traversal if I don't know the tree structure.