# how to create project hierarchical view in pyqt inside main window

Tags: parsing, pyqt, rule, yara

I'm trying to implement a project structure viewer to view the structure of a specific programming language. and this project structure view should look like a the tree widget in PyQT , like project explorer in Eclipse.

Example:

if my code is :

```
rule Adzok
{
    meta:
        author = " Kevin Breen <kevin@techanarchy.net>"
        Description = "Adzok Rat"
        Versions = "Free 1.0.0.3,"
    strings:
        $a1 = "config.xmlPK"
        $a2 = "key.classPK"
        $a3 = "svd$1.classPK"
    condition:
    7 of ($a*)
}
```

Check the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just use a `QTreeWidget`?

Comment: Answers to this question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805047/qtreewidget-to-mirror-python-dictionary) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898718/multi-level-qtreeview). You would just need to provide your structure as a python dictionary.